# Getting mssql_connect to work on MAMP Pro

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

Followed this tutorial http://thinkinkless.com/node/88 3 times  now in an attempt to get mssql_connect to work on my mac (Mountain Lion) and no luck. I get the same error every time.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /Volumes/www/vhosts/_playground/sql.php on line 50
```

Any help would be amazing at this point.

Running PHP 5.4.10, freetds 0.91

Current php.ini setup:

```
extension=imap.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=mssql.so
```

Comment: run `phpinfo()` and then add `extension=php_mssql.dll` to `php.ini`.

Comment: Same error as before. I'm OSX so I'm not sure that a dll solution will work...

Comment: Oops, my mistake, isn't it `.so`? Better question, does PDO or MySQLi work? Also, when you edit `php.ini`, you need to reload/restart apache/httpd.

Comment: I'll add a link here so you can check it out... http://www.rizenclients.com/phpinfo.html . Converted to html because I'm running these tests locally.

Comment: Try redownloading the `.so` http://etresoft.org/opensource/mssql.so

Comment: Mac php distro ships with Windows .dll' however I wouldn't try and convert the .dll to an .so. You have PDO enabled, I would consider using that for your DB work.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I have to connect to a linked read-only server. The site was originally built in .net so we're in the process of figuring out how to import the data from this external server :)

Comment: still no luck... not sure what's going on here.. I'll give the PDO method a shot